# What’s wrong with my potted tree?

Tags: plant-health, fungus, evergreens

This is my first tree and I got it in December. It was doing well initially, but these last couple of weeks have been difficult. The tree is wilting (see attached) and there is almost a dust-like dark grey fungus in the soil. I dig it out every day, but am unsure as to whether the fungus has this negative impact on the tree’s condition. Why does my tree look like this? How can I make my tree healthy again? Any help or advice is appreciated! [image]

Comment: Is the tree a Stone Pine?

Comment: Are you growing this indoors?

Comment: Yes, I’m growing this indoors. No, the tree isn’t a stone pine. I’m not entire sure what kind of tree it is (it didn’t have a tag) but I suspect it’s a blue spruce sapling.

Comment: Generally not enough light indoors for an average tree.

Comment: I don't think it's a blue spruce (wrong color and it appears to have a pine-like needle arrangement). I mentioned Stone Pine because they're commonly sold here in Wisconsin by some of the box stores as Christmas trees; I'm guessing that they're sold elsewhere in the US as well. They're not hardy outdoors here, and die just about this time of the year regardless of care. I have seen one live for 12 months, but it died the following January anyways.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to address this? Even though I’m not sure what kind of tree it is, are there any remedies you would recommend?

Comment: Got it in December. Is this one of those supermarket xmas trees? It might think it is supposed to be dormant right now. And it might have been charged up with fertilizer to make it green for a week at xmas.

Comment: Conifers don't like being kept in houses over the winter. And, if  it is a supermarket or box store Christmas tree, then the "soil" in the pot is probably terrible (our little stone pine's soil was certainly crap). Most conifers (except yews) do not come back once all of their foliage dies, so I think your tree is dead, I'm sad to say.  If you want to try, repot it in a good soilless mix, water well (once) and keep it out of direct sunlight. Water only when the soil is dry/pot is light. If the tree is dead, the soil will remain wet for a long time as there are no roots to take up the water.